# How does pop-up window based Google OAuth work?

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-oauth

I have been learning about `OAuth` recently, and observing site's that make use of `OAuth`. I have observed, when I attempt to login into [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/) using Google OAuth, it pop's open a new window where I can sign in with my Google account, and then it closes the popped open window after a successful sign in. And somehow Udemy get's to know that I have signed in with Google, which I am not sure how.

This looks to be very different from the regular Google OAuth based sign in on many other site's which load the Google sign in page in the same window and redirect it back to the original website that I was browsing without any pop up window. This process is currently my understanding of how OAuth generally works, so I am getting confused with how Udemy is doing it differently with a pop up window and without a redirect uri.

Can someone kindly explain how does pop up window based OAuth work ? Does it use cookies, if so, how is it access the cookie being generated from the pop up window ?

Steps that happen at Udemy for Google OAuth:

1. User clicks Google sign in option on Udemy Log in page
2. Google OAuth Pop Up Window, allowing the user to select from several accounts
3. User selects their account and the Pop up window closes
4. User is taken to Udemy with the user being logged in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find the answer (that's how I found this post), and since I hopefully figured it out, here it is...

A possible solution I've implemented involves using the server-side flow with my backend, typically performed via the implicit grant flow:

From the client side (e.g., React, located at `example.com/signup/`), on 'Sign Up with Google' click it makes a fetch request to the backend that initiates entire process. The backend saves the state in the user session and returns a redirect URL to Google, including all the necessary query parameters with (in the case of Django) `sessionid` cookie. Normally, a backend like Django would directly redirect you to the Google site.

Then, the client opens a popup window using that redirect URL with necessary query parameters returned from the initial request:

```js
let popupWindow = window.open(redirect_url, "popup", windowFeatures);
```

This popup window (located at mentioned `redirect_url`-`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/...`) allows the user to log in.
On successful authentication, Google redirects the user back to a page specified by the `redirect_uri` (`redirect_uri` is a query parameter, part of the `redirect_url` that opened new window). Let's say `example.com/signup/google/p/?state=f2fdf...`, everything happens in a popup, child window.

The redirect from Google includes these query parameters: `state`, `code`, and `scope`.

The biggest challenge was to access those query parameters in the main window (`example.com/signup/`) since they are contained in the child popup window (`example.com/signup/google/p/?state=f2fdf...`).

Due to Same Origin Policy restrictions, accessing content **in** the popup window **from** the parent window is not possible, as Google doesn't have CORS headers for your website.

However, it's possible to do something opposite-send a message **from** the popup child window **to** the main window:

```js
  // opener- main, parent window that opened this popup
  const openerWindow = window.opener;

  if (openerWindow && !openerWindow.closed) {
    const openerOrigin = openerWindow.location.origin;

    const url = window.location.href;
    const questionMarkIndex = url.indexOf("?");
    if (questionMarkIndex !== -1) {
      const queryParams = url.slice(questionMarkIndex);
      openerWindow.postMessage(queryParams, openerOrigin);
```

This runs when `example.com/signup/google/p/?state=f2fdf...` is opened and sends the `queryParams` to the main parent window, which can be captured by an eventListener:

```js
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
      if (...) {
        loginUser(event.params).then((response) => {
          ...
        });
      }
      popupWindow.close();
```

The `loginUser` function triggers a request to the backend, which further validates the received query parameters with Google. Upon successful validation, the backend logs in the user and returns, in my case, a JWT.

In the context of the client flow, Google likely utilizes a similar mechanism. Instead of redirecting within a popup window as I've implemented, Google may include a script (inside a popup window) that sends a similar message with a `token` to the main window (I think Google provides some library for this).